# Cómo se debe de utilizar correctamente dimens.xml en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

He estado leyendo sobre el tema y voy a reformular la pregunta.

Tengo un Layout en el cual tengo un TextView, quería que el mismo TextView se visualizara de manera similar en los dos terminales físicos que utilizo para hacer pruebas, en uno el TextView se ve en una línea y en otro me lo saca en dos, supongo que es debido a la diferente densidad de pixeles que tienen.

Leyendo sobre el tema creo que la mejor solución para esto es utilizar tamaños de dimensiones diferentes por medio de dimens.xml.

He creado un ejemplo para la utilización de dimens.xml y ver su funcionamiento, pero creo que tengo algún error porque siempre me saca el mismo tamaño del TextView en los dos terminales, os pongo el Layout.xml para que le echéis un vistazo y me digáis que es lo que hay mal.

El ejemplo lo estoy ejecutando en los dos terminales, uno es un Samsung S8 y el otro un Huawei P20 Lite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Prueba de texto para diferentes pantallas en Android"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.41"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.044" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text1">10sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

sw430dp\dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text1">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

sw560dp\dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="text1">14sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué width está en 0dp? ¿Probaste con android:weightSum="2"?

Comment: Lo pone automáticamente el Constraint Widget cuando pongo el margen en modo Match Constraints.

Comment: Me pregunto lo mismo que Franqo, with no debería de tener 0dp, ya que es el ancho de la vista agrega un wrap_content al atributo y mira si eso solventa el problema.

Comment: Ya está cambiado, con el mismo resultado.

Comment: ¿Probaste con android:weightSum="2"? Repito

Comment: Franqo Balsamo, lo he probado con el mismo resultado

Comment: Lee [*Cómo brindar compatibilidad con diferentes tamaños de pantalla*](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes) en la documentación de Android.

Comment: Ya lo he leído y no termino de comprenderlo, puse esta pregunta para ver si alguien me lo explicaba con algún ejemplo práctico, pensaba que no debía de ser tan complicado adaptar dos TextViews a diferentes tamaños de pantalla.

Comment: y la lógica que se encarga de determinar que archivo debe usar para cada dispositivo???

Comment: según la documentación que he consultado se supone que la aplicación se encarga de determinar que dimens.xml debe utilizar en función del tamaño del dispositivo.